# Como armazenar dados de uma struct em um vector (c++)

Tags: c++, struct, armazenamento

estou com uma dificuldade no armazenamento de informações dentro de um vector. Preciso armazenar informações como nome, senha e numero da conta de um usuário, dessa forma estou usando uma struct

```
typedef struct  {
  int conta;
  string nome;
  double saldo;
  int senha;
} Cliente ;
```

E um vector do tipo da struct

```
vector <Cliente> clientes_;
```

E a função na qual salvo as informações de um cliente é essa:

```
char opcaoMenu(char opc){
  Cliente cliente;
  do{
    cin >> opc;
    if (opc == '1'){
       acessarConta();
    }
    else if (opc =='2'){
      clientes_.push_back(cadastrarConta());
      acessarConta();
    } 
    else{
      cout << "Opção inválida! Divite novamente!" << endl<< "Escolha uma opção >>>  ";
    }
  }while (opc > '2');
  return opc;
```

}

A função de cadastro do push_back é essa

```
Cliente cadastrarConta() {
  Cliente cliente;
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "Digite seu nome: ";
  getline(cin, cliente.nome);
  cout << "Digite uma senha nuḿerica: ";
  cin >> cliente.senha;
  cliente.conta = (cliente.senha + rand() % 8000 + 1000);
  cout << "Sua conta é: " << cliente.conta;

  return cliente;
}
```

Quando dou o make, obtenho essa saída no terminal:

> g++ funcoes.cpp main.cpp -o teste.o
>   /tmp/ccwJox4M.o:(.bss+0x0): múltiplas definições de "clientes_"
>   /tmp/ccyG79Ya.o:(.bss+0x0): definido primeiro aqui
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1

Só preciso saber onde estou errando.
Qualquer coisa o repositório do projeto é esse:
https://gitlab.com/peidrao/caixa-eletronico

Comment: Tome cuidado com using namespace, principalmente em headers.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema não esta em como armazenar a struct, pelo seu erro, o que esta acontecendo é um problema no link, recomendo ver [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904643/error-with-multiple-definitions-of-function)

O que eu te recomendo é mover a declaração de `vector <Cliente> clientes_` para `funcoes.cpp` onde é o único lugar que você utiliza ela

De toda forma também é altamente recomendado não colocar `using namespace`em cabeçalhos.

Exemplificando você esta carregando a mesma coisas em dois arquivos diferentes e o linker não sabe onde colocar se na `main`ou nas `funcoes`, mesmo com seu `#define` ele não vai funcionar porque você explicitamente importou os cabeçalhos nos dois códigos fonte.

Answer (score 0):

Não tentei reproduzir, mas se eu tivesse que chutar, eu diria que você está definindo clientes_ no header. Desta forma, toda vez que você inclui funcoes.hpp, uma nova definição de clientes_ é gerada e "múltiplas definições" acontece.

Para resolver isso, bote a keyword "extern" na frente de vector clientes_.

```
extern vector <Cliente> clientes_;
```

Com isso, você estará apenas declarando "clientes_" e não definindo. Portanto, é necessário que seja definido (apenas uma vez). Para isso, em funcoes.cpp, escreva vector  clientes_;

```
vector <Cliente> clientes_;
```

Para mais detalhes em declaração x definição, leia: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration/